# R: read xlsx not reading excel file when rows surpass 100k

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation, readxl

Looks like when I try to read more than 100k rows from an excel file, I get this error message:

Error: Cell references aren't uniformly A1 or R1C1 format:

```
df <- read_xlsx("Test.xlsx",
                 col_names=T,sheet="Data",
                 range="G1:AL170000")
```

If I try to read under 100k rows, it does it fine. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: Quite possibly a bug in the package such that it can't properly parse  "XYabcdef" ,i.e. if there are more than 5 characters in the row-number section it chokes.  I would recommend sending a bug report to the maintainer of the package.  Is this from the `officer` package function?   Have you tried any other  excel-to-R packages?

Comment: BTW,  it's often easier to save the spreadsheet to CSV format and use the standard file-reading tools to import your data

Answer (score 1):

Hi I came across the exact same problem and found this solution in [the RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/read-excel-range-limits/6894) and [see also](https://github.com/rsheets/cellranger)

For your problem I would go with:

```
df <- read_xlsx("Test.xlsx",
                 col_names=T,sheet="Data",
                 range=cell_limits(c(1,6), c(NA,38)))
```